# Removing dense grid lines & convert into clear image - opencv - python

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, image-processing, text-recognition

I want to extract the text from this image. I'm a newbie in opencv. I've tried various opencv codes across various questions, but none is working for me.

How can I extract text from this? Or maybe remove grid lines & that circular bulge in the middle so that image is straightened & then I can extract the text.

Any help is appreciated.

One of the Sample codes I tried - [this](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/52089/removing-noisy-lines-from-image-opencv-python)

[image]

Comment: You want to remove the grid for this specific example? Because whatever you write, it will work for this image, maybe two or three more. For other captchas, it will not work. The captcha is specifically designed to fail automatic detections

Comment: It's a very rudimentary type of captcha and all images are coming the same, I've explored the API. I think it should work for now. I've a very small & temp usecase

Comment: I would try to fill in the pure blue and red lines. You can get them by thresholding them on the respective channels. Then fill these pixels with an average of their immediate neighbours, this should work... for this specific case.

Comment: Tried what you said. Can you help why this is not working - https://gist.github.com/pankajsinghal/5060eb7eb994e87ff0e118cf911fb18a

Comment: if you already tried stuff, include them in your question: code + results so far

Comment: I tried after you said

Comment: have mentioned the output in gist itself

Answer (score 0):

I did the following approach:

- get pixels that are not strong on a target channel
- bitwise and on these pixels to get rid of the lines
- fill pixels with mean of neighbors based on grid

The functions are written here:

```
    # get weak pixels by comparing each channel
    def getWeak(im, targetChannel, Factor):
        r,g,b = cv2.split(im) # split image
        if targetChannel == 0:
            target = r
            mask = (target<Factor*b)*(target<Factor*g)
        elif targetChannel == 1:
            target = g
            mask = (target<Factor*r)*(target<Factor*b)
        elif targetChannel == 2:
            target = b
            mask = (target<Factor*r)*(target<Factor*g)
        else:
            raise Exception("Invalid channel number!\nInput 0 for red, 1 for green, 2 for blue")
        return np.array(mask, dtype = np.uint8)
    def fill_with_mean(image): # define the fill with mean function for the images
        def mean_filter(arr): # define mean filter
            return np.mean(arr) # return mean of an array
        mean_filled_image = generic_filter(image, mean_filter, size=4, mode='constant', cval=0.0) 
        return mean_filled_image # return the mean filled image
```

The implementation: (please note that I usually convert my images to RGB for easier plotting with matplotlib):

```
im = cv2.cvtColor(cv2.imread("GridCaptacha.png"), cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB) # read image
Numbers = cv2.bitwise_and(im,im, mask = getWeak(im, 2, 1.1)+getWeak(im, 0, 1.1)) # btwise and, using addition (OR) on the masks
NumbersGray = cv2.cvtColor(Numbers, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY) # convert to gray
# add contrast to image
NumbersGray[NumbersGray<50] = 1 # make numbers positive class
NumbersGray[NumbersGray>=50] = 0 # and the lines negative class
# plotting...
fig, axs = plt.subplots(nrows= 3, ncols = 1, sharex = True, sharey = True)
axs[0].imshow(im)
axs[0].set_title("Raw")
axs[1].imshow(Numbers)
axs[1].set_title("After pixel selection")
axs[2].imshow(fill_with_mean(NumbersGray), cmap = "gray")
axs[2].set_title("After averaging")
for ax in axs:
    ax.axis("off")
```

Here are the results:

[image: results]

The libraries:

```
import cv2
%matplotlib notebook
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.ndimage import generic_filter
```

P.S: I have answered a few of these types of questions here so far. I mentioned it before, and I mention it again: captchas were never meant to be decodable with the usual tesseract. So while these questions are fun to answer, the limitations are very obvious to a lot of people here.